# get image full size using php

Tags: php, image, image-size

i would like to save image in original size from a given url.

For example, i have the following site: *

I am possible to get all the images from this url but the size is very small. All the images have an img tag with source looking like /fileadmin/media/images/cat_thumb/xxx.jpg

But the img tag is inside an a href link which is showing the  image in fullsize. And i need this img, not the small one

Note that this size is only an example, and i am looking for some generic solutin to find images in original/thumbnail size.

Here is a code snippet i am using to save the small images...

`$html = file_get_html($url);`
`foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {` 
    `echo url_to_absolute($url, $element->src), "</br>";`
`}`

Comment: You'll have to follow each link and see whether it leads to an image; then fetch that image. No way around it. There is no generic way to tell the original image from a thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is confusing so my answer could be off.

Something like this should set you on the right path (not tested)

```
$html = file_get_html($url); 
foreach($html->find('img')->parent('a') as $element) 
{ 
 $page_url = url_to_absolute($url, $element->href); 
 $page_html = file_get_html($page_url); 
}
```

But the only true way you can check an image width/height is by copying it to your server first and using `getimagesize()` to get height and width.